# python 3 :number coming automatically

Tags: python, python-3.6

[myimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R94q9.jpg)

Hi,

i have written this code below, every time i run it it gives some number like 16, 23 see attached jpeg image it has number 13, can someone explain?

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv

print ("I will show you magic")
print (open(filename).read())

target = open(filename, "w")
target.truncate()

# now i will show you more magic

print("lets do this")

line1 = input("what do you want to print type it in, ok?, ")
line2 = input("i dont understand this, ")
line3 = input("type again please, ")
print (target.write(f"{line1} \n{line2} \n{line3}"))
target = open(filename)
print (target.read())
```

Comment: Whats the content of  `filename` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the return value of `target.write()`. That method returns the number of characters written. From the [`TextIOBase.write()` documenatation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write):

> Write the string *s* to the stream and return the number of characters written.

The 13 indicates you wrote 13 characters to a file. If you se 26, then you wrote twice as much information to the file. If you didn't want to print that, simply remove the `print()` call, and only call `target.write()`.